# Communicating with nearby devices

Tags: firefox-os

I want to develop a FirefoxOS privileged app that can send text messages to nearby devices.

Android app can use Bluetooth or Wifi P2P. But FirefoxOS privileged apps cannot use Bluetooth/Wifi API. These are only available for certified apps.

Privileged apps can use TCP socket API. Is this the only way?
Is there any way to get available IP addresses on LAN?

Answer (score 2):

@Kazhik, unfortunately right now, that is the only way to go. And the explanation for that is that by using the socket API you can implement any protocol on top of TCP, such as IMAP, IRC, POP, HTTP, etc., or even build your own to sustain any specific needs you could have.

Since certified apps can only be included by the oem, access to Bluetooth or WiFi information API aren't a viable option now.

Comment: I hope it will change in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Me too, it certainly is a downside on developing for the platform right now. Things could be much easier by making use of API's that provide a more elegant approach to some problems.

Answer (score 0):

At today's date (September 18, 2015) the WebIDE **supports** installing certified apps in older Firefox OS versions like `1.3` and in physical devices.
I tried installing the Gaia test apps (these are certified) in one Alcatel OT FireC and everything worked perfectly fine ;)

Answer (score 0):

DNS-SD (part of the Zeroconf specification) allows you to broadcast and receive "advertisements" from other devices on the local network. That requires UDP and TCP permissions, which means a "privileged" app, as you thought. That's not a problem, unless you need to distribute the app outside of the Firefox Marketplace.

There's an implementation of DNS-SD for JavaScript at https://github.com/justindarc/dns-sd.js

For compatibility with other messaging apps, you might want to implement XMPP:
http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html

Comment: You might consider adding DNS-SD support to Loqui IM; it's open-source: https://github.com/loqui/im